# Update a JS array value with a global variable based on checkbox (true/false) form input

Tags: javascript, php, forms, global-variables

I'm using a WorldPay JS function to create a payment form. This function creates a TOKEN that can be reusable or not. I need to update the 'reusable' flag based on a form input (checkbox) but I can't get the global variable (reuse) to update. I've created a function CHECKED that updates the variable but the WorldPay JS just ignores it. I think is due the window.onload status, but I don't know how to fix it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
 <?php
include('./header.php');
require_once('./init.php');
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <script src="https://cdn.worldpay.com/v1/worldpay.js"></script>    
        <script type='text/javascript'>
            var reuse = false;
            function Checked(){
                reuse = document.getElementById('check').checked;
                Worldpay.submitTemplateForm();
            }

            window.onload = function() {
                Worldpay.useTemplateForm({
                'clientKey':'ENTER CLIENT KEY',
                'form':'paymentForm',
                'paymentSection':'paymentSection',
                'display':'inline',
                'type':'card',
                'reusable': reuse,
                'saveButton':false,
                'callback':function(obj){
                    if (obj && obj.token && obj.paymentMethod) {
                    var _el = document.createElement('input');
                    _el.value = obj.token;
                    _el.type = 'hidden';
                    _el.name = 'token';
                    document.getElementById('paymentForm').appendChild(_el);
                    var _name = document.createElement('input');
                    _name.value = obj.paymentMethod.name;
                    _name.type = 'hidden';
                    _name.name = 'customer';
                    document.getElementById('paymentForm').appendChild(_name);
                    document.getElementById('paymentForm').submit();

                    }

                }
                });
                }
        </script>

    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="./test.php" id="paymentForm" method="post">
            <!-- all other fields you want to collect, e.g. name and shipping address -->
            <div id='paymentSection'></div>
            <div>
            <input type="checkbox" id='check'>
            <input type="submit" value="Place Order" onclick="Checked()" />
            </div>

        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

NOTE: I've removed the client ID so the code won't run.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Keep in mind that the code should allow replication, don´t remove anything if it is required.

Comment: Hi David, I do understand that and I haven't removed the tag (clientKey) but I can't share my credentials. I was hoping someone would be able to provide a solution just based on the question on how to update a value within a function that is set as window.onload. The code was just to give more context. Thanks.

Comment: Here is the link in case someone wants to try the WorldPay payment APIs. https://online.worldpay.com/login

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use function "checked" on window.onload like this:

```
  window.onload = function() {
            Worldpay.useTemplateForm({
           //code....
          )}
 function Checked(){
    //code....
         }
```

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work. I don't think you can add the function as window.onload as the user needs to select the checkbox first, it seems it needs to be onclick. I was hoping to update the variable reuse before triggering the Worldpay.submitTemplateForm() function.